# Rails 4 - Rolify with renewal date for role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, rolify

I'm trying to setup roles in my rails app with Rolify.

I have a CRUD model setup for roles. I'm about to start exploring how certain users can assign scoped roles to other users.

Is there a way I can allow users who are permitted to assign roles, to specify a renewal date, by which they need to confirm that the user is continuing in that role?

At the moment, my roles table only has associations to resource and user, and a string attribute called :name (for the name of the role).

Can I add a boolean for true/false on whether the role has an expiry date, and if it does, when a renewal notice should be issued?

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This can be good idea:**

1. Create a table for roles and permission.
2. add a field has_expired in that table.
3. When you save permission set expiry date.
4. When user logins test expire date.
5. Then set has_expired to true
6. If you are using cancancan gem then in ability.rb model:

   `if user.role.has_expired?
   cannot :manage, Role
   end`

**Hope it helps**

Comment: @Pradeep_Sapkota - thanks. I'm using pundit for authorisations. Do you mean I add the has_expired field to the roles table? I could then use Pundit to exclude anyone whose role has expired. In that case I should add a date field to the role table to set an expiry date

Comment: Sorry I use devise with cancan and I know nothing about pundit.